# Blender 2.8 beta Denoise bug?

Tags: denoise

I have this problem when I am rendering in Cycles, the render takes the time to process the denoise tiles, however, I have unchecked the denoising filter in view layer tab.

I also turned off any render compositing in case that was the issue.

Comment: How long does it take?

Comment: So it's for a simple bare bones render of a single plane with some holdout objects in front. Takes 40sec per frame with denoise. In my job that's longer than I'd like. Render should take at most 10secs per frame.